# Control flow issue with node/redis and callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

Please could I ask for some advice on a control flow issue with node and redis? (aka Python coder trying to get used to JavaScript)

I don't understand why `client.smembers` and `client.get` (Redis lookups) need to be callbacks rather than simply being statements - it makes life very complicated.

Basically I'd like to query a set, and then when I have the results for the set, I need to carry out a get for each result. *When I've got all the data*, I need to broadcast it back to the client.

Currently I do this inside two callbacks, using a global object, which seems messy. I'm not even sure if it's safe (will the code wait for one `client.get` to complete before starting another?).

The current code looks like this:

```
var all_users = [];
// Get all the users for this page.
client.smembers("page:" + current_page_id, function (err, user_ids ) {
  // Now get the name of each of those users.
  for (var i = 0; i < user_ids.length; i++) {
     client.get('user:' + user_ids[i] + ':name', function(err, name) {
       var myobj = {};
       myobj[user_ids[i]] = name;
       all_users.push(myobj);  
       // Broadcast when we have got to the end of the loop, 
       // so all users have been added to the list - 
       // is this the best way? It seems messy.  
       if (i === (user_ids.length - 1)) {
           socket.broadcast('all_users', all_users); 
       }
     });       
   }
 });
```

But this seems very messy. Is it really the best way to do this? How can I be sure that all lookups have been performed before calling `socket.broadcast`?

*scratches head* Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why `client.smembers` and `client.get` (Redis lookups) need to be callbacks rather than simply being statements - it makes life very complicated.

That's what Node is. (I'm pretty sure that this topic was discussed more than enough times here, look through other questions, it's definitely there)

> How can I be sure that all lookups have been performed before calling `socket.broadcast`?

That's what is `err` for in callback function. This is kinda Node's standard - first parameter in callback is error object (`null` if everything fine). So just use something like this to be sure no errors occurred:

```
if (err) {
  ...    // handle errors.
  return // or not, it depends.
}

... // process results
```

> But this seems very messy.

You'll get used to it. I'm actually finding it nice, when code is well formatted and project is cleverly structured.

Other ways are:

- Using libraries to control async code-flow ([Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async), [Step.js](https://github.com/creationix/step), etc.)
- If spaghetti-style code is what you think mess is, define some functions to process results and pass them as parameters instead of anonymous ones.

Comment: Totally agree with the questioners observations, I am struggling too with these concepts. `That's what Node is` seems like it's a bit snobby, sorry.

Comment: @SSHThis right on the [main page](http://nodejs.org/) of Node's website it explicity says so — async I/O. I can only speculate on reasons that made you choose technology that relies on concepts you don't (and not willing to) understand. Try to get it and you'll love it, if not — choose something different.

Answer (score 0):

If you totally dislike writing stuff callback-style, you might want to try [streamlinejs](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs):

```
var all_users = [];
// Get all the users for this page.
var user_ids = client.smembers("page:" + current_page_id, _);
// Now get the name of each of those users.
for (var i = 0; i < user_ids.length; i++) {
  var name = client.get('user:' + user_ids[i] + ':name', _);
  var myobj = {};
  myobj[user_ids[i]] = name;
  all_users.push(myobj);  
}
socket.broadcast('all_users', all_users);
```

Note that a disadvantage of this variant is that only one username will be fetched at a time. Also, you should still be aware of what this code really does.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I'd like to know though: what is the correct way to write it callback-style? Just so I know the right way before doing it the simple way :)

Answer (score 0):

[Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) is a great library and you should take a look. Why ? Clean code / process / easy to track .. etc

Also, keep in mind that all your async function will be processed after your for loop. In you exemple, it may result in wrong "i" value. Use closure :

```
 for (var i = 0; i < user_ids.length; i++) { (function(i) {
 client.get('user:' + user_ids[i] + ':name', function(err, name) {
   var myobj = {};
   myobj[user_ids[i]] = name;
   all_users.push(myobj);  
   // Broadcast when we have got to the end of the loop, 
   // so all users have been added to the list - 
   // is this the best way? It seems messy.  
   if (i === (user_ids.length - 1)) {
       socket.broadcast('all_users', all_users); 
   }
 });       
})(i)}
```

What you should do to know when it's finish is use a recursive pattern like async ( i think ) do. It's much simple then doing it yourself.

```
async.series({
  getMembers: function(callback) {
     client.smembers("page:" + current_page_id, callback);
  }
}, function(err, results) {
   var all_users = [];
   async.forEachSeries(results.getMembers, function(item, cb) {
    all_users.push(item);
    cb();
   }, function(err) {
      socket.broadcast('all_users', all_users); 
   });
});
```

This code may not be valid, but you should be able to figure out how to do it.

Step library is good too ( and only 30~ line of code i think)

Comment: For the loop, he could also just do .forEach

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why client.smembers and client.get (Redis lookups)
> need to be callbacks rather than simply being statements - it makes
> life very complicated.

Right, so everyone agrees callback hell is *no bueno*. As of this writing, callbacks are a dying feature of Node. Unfortunately, the Redis library does not have native support for returning Promises.

But there is a module you can require in like so:

`const util = require("util");`

This is a standard library that is included in the Node runtime and has a bunch of utility functions we can use, one of them being "promisify":
https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Now of course when you asked this question seven years ago, **util.promisify(original)** did not exist as it was added in with the release of -**v 8.0.0**, so we can now update this question with an updated answer.

So **promisify** is a function and we can pass it a function like `client.get()` and it will return a new function that take the nasty callback behavior and instead wraps it up nice and neat to make it return a Promise.

So **promisify** takes any function that accepts a callback as the last argument and makes it instead return a Promise and it sounds like that's the exact behavior that you wanted seven years ago and we are afforded today.

```
const util = require("util");
client.get = util.promisify(client.get);
```

So we are passing a reference to the `.get()` function to `util.promisify()`.

This takes your function, wraps it up so instead of implementing a callback, it instead returns a Promise. So `util.promisify()` returns a new function that has been *promisified*.

So you can take that new function and override the existing one on `client.get()`. Nowadays, you do not have to use a callback for Redis lookup. So now you can use the `async/await` syntax like so:

`const cachedMembers = await client.get('user:' + user_ids[i]);`

So we wait for this to be resolved and whatever it resolves with will be assigned to `cachedMembers`.

The code can be even further cleaned up to be more updated by using an ES6 array helper method instead of your `for` loop. I hope this answer is useful for current users, otherwise the OP was obsolete.