# Redis, node.js and Javascript Callback Scoping / Flow

Tags: design-patterns, node.js, socket.io

I've been exploring javascript more deeply lately, playing around with a node,redis,socket.io,express simple webapp.

I think I've come to a problem that is an example of the fundamental difference between JS and PHP, which is what I've been using the last few years.

I've written this callback and need to return a stack of data from redis

```
app.get('/deck', function(request, response) { 
  dealer.sort('cards', 'BY', 'deal:*->timestamp', 'GET', 'card:*->card_key',
    function(err, card_keys) {
      var deck = []; 
      for (k in card_keys) { 
        dealer.hget(card_keys[k], 'data', function(err, card_data) { 
          var deal = eval('(' + card_data +')');
          deals.push(cards);
        }); 
      }   
      response.json(deals);
    }   
  );  
});
```

Now first I thought it was a variable scoping problem so I rewrote with a closure (did I use this term correctly?) which didn't work because I am writing this in synchronous mind set.
I realize that this is essentially synchronous and sends the data out before it is collected. The design is wrong.

I can rewrite the function to use socket.io's emit function to send data as it is collected.

But are there design patterns for handling synchronous data? What if I want to show the last 10 cards in order? Do I send the data over anyway and have client side code queue up 10, and trigger an event that sorts and then control display?

Edit: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971945/control-flow-issue-with-node-redis-and-callbacks) which essentially mine, except that I would like to figure out how to design this without relying an synchronous library.

Comment: you can't use async function in your for loop. You should use something like async or streamlinejs.

Comment: Thanks, but for my own good, I would like to understand how to structure this in a callback way without relying on those libraries.

Comment: Check both link i posted, it should answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function(err, card_keys) {
    var deck = [];
    for (k in card_keys) {
        // whole bunch of async actions
        dealer.hget(card_keys[k], 'data', function(err, card_data) {
            var deal = eval('(' + card_data + ')');
            deals.push(cards);
        });
    }
    // sync action
    response.json(deals);
}
```

You already know `response.json` fires before the `hget` are done.

The answer is reference counting

```
function(err, card_keys) {
    var deck = [];
    var count = Object.keys(card_keys).length;

    function next() {
        if (--count === 0) {
            response.json(deals.sort(sortThem)); 
        }  
    }

    for (k in card_keys) {
        dealer.hget(card_keys[k], 'data', function(err, card_data) {
            var deal = JSON.parse(card_data);
            deals.push(cards);
            next();
        });
    }
}
```

You have two other minor problems

- using `eval` instead of JSON.parse
- your deals array is unordered because hget is asynchronous, so you need a sorting function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, trying to grok this all. One quick question, why Object.keys(card_keys).length instead of card_keys.length?

Comment: @jskulski wasn't sure if `card_keys` was an array. I mean you did use a `for..in` loop over it and `for..in` over an array is a bad practice

Comment: @Raynos well I'm very new at this :) Thanks for all the tips, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this without using another library is using the "recursive pattern".

You can't do some asynchronious call in a for loop.

**card_keys** need to be an array.

Some useful link about how to write for loop :

1. http://tech.richardrodger.com/2011/04/21/node-js-%E2%80%93-how-to-write-a-for-loop-with-callbacks/
2. http://metaduck.com/post/2675027550/asynchronous-iteration-patterns-in-node-js

**EDIT:** Like Raynos said, you should use reference counting instead.

I suggest you use a lib and do something like this with async:

```
...
var deals = []
async.forEach(card_keys, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
    } else {
        deals.push(results); // For each card
    }
}, function(err) {
    callback(deals); // When it's completed
});
...
```

This is how async is doing the forEach

```
async.forEach = function (arr, iterator, callback) {
    if (!arr.length) {
        return callback();
    }
    var completed = 0;
    _forEach(arr, function (x) {
        iterator(x, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                callback = function () {};
            }
            else {
                completed += 1;
                if (completed === arr.length) {
                    callback();
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**Edit: Which one is faster : reference counting or recursive pattern**

I did 100 basic query :

Resurcive pattern : 7161,7528, 7226 MS

Reference counting: 7515, 7256, 7364 MS

Recursive pattern code :

```
var req = "select id from membre";

var time = new Date().getTime();

var test = function(value,callback) {
   if(value < 100) {
      client.query(req, function(err, results) {
          test(++value,callback);
      });
   } else {
       callback();
   }
}

test(0, function() {
   var time2 = new Date().getTime();
   console.log(time2-time);
   client.end();
});
```

Reference counting code :

```
var req = "select id from membre";

var time = new Date().getTime();

var test = function(callback) {

   var c = 100;
   function next() {
      if(--c === 0) callback();
   }

  for(var i =0; i < c; i++) {
       client.query(req, function(err) {
          next();
       });
   }
};


test(function() {
   var time2 = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(t2-t);
   client.end();
});
```

**Why it's almost the same time ?** Since it's **mysql** we don't gain that much from the "async" from node-js in **this** situation. See comments.

Comment: "recursive pattern" is wrong, that's not asynchronous, that's waterfall and slow as hell.

Comment: Good point. I would not say slow as hell ... but reference counting is  better, a lot

Comment: recursion means only one task is running at a time. This means zero parallelism which means slow as hell

Comment: [Your benchmark is broken, don't know why](http://jsperf.com/recursion-vs-reference)

Comment: No I/O calls in yours and one in mine. Thats the difference.

Comment: ... I'm emulating I/O. Which is simply an asychronous action using setTimeout, which is asynchronous.

Comment: I used node-mysql, maybe it's related to the drivers. May explain why some "series" and "parallele" mysql calls was taking the same time. Thx

Comment: I see why your code doesn't go faster. It's because your using mysql and it's using a transaction. So even though the reference counting code sends 100 mysql requests in parallel, mysql only processes it one at a time. This is why we use a real database and it's a good example of how one piece of blocking code (mysql) becomes your entire application bottleneck

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing this properly since the server could respond before the db queries have returned their results.

You should instead use control flow libraries like [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step) or [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async). Learn more about them on [dailyjs](http://dailyjs.com/2011/11/14/popular-control-flow/).

I personally use Step, so here's show I would do it:

```
app.get('/deck', function(request, response) { 
  dealer.sort('cards', 'BY', 'deal:*->timestamp', 'GET', 'card:*->card_key',
    function(err, card_keys) {
      var deals = [], iterations = Object.keys(card_keys).length;
      // iterations contains the length of 'card_keys'
      Step(
        function queries() {
          var deck = [];
          if (!iterations) { this(null); return; } // if no cards
          for (k in card_keys) {
            dealer.hget(card_keys[k], 'data', function(err, card_data) {
              var deal;
              if (err) {
                throw new Error('Database error');
              } else {
                // we decrease the number of iterations until it gets to 0
                // and then we trigger the callback, since every query has
                // returned its result
                iterations--;
                deal = eval('(' + card_data +')');
                deals.push(cards);
                if (!iterations) { this(deals); } // callback function called
              }
            });
          }
        },
        function render(deals) {
          response.json(deals);
        }
      );
    }
  );
});
```